# Determining the range of input feature values

Tags: feature-selection, experiment-design, feature-engineering, importance, exploratory-data-analysis

I have an application (numerical simulation) in hand, for which I am generating my own data.

Initially, I wanted to generate a small subset of data and perform initial ML model training. I was wondering if there is a method to statistically determine the valid range of every input feature value (i.e the min value and the max value).

I am obtaining the feature importance using sensitivity analysis methods, but I have no overview of the range of values.

Could you please help me?

Comment: you will need to give us more information. What are you trying to predict, what are the features why do you need the range of input features, why do you need the feature importance and in general what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Dataset - Numerical Finite Element simulation. The test case is a cantilever beam. Where in I am trying to predict the probability of the structure to fail (predict a number in between 0-1)
I will be using input parameters (numerical and no categorical features) like, material weight, initial force applied, etc ( in total 7 input parameters, all numerical).
I wanted to generate around 1000 samples, but the simulation is time-intensive. So, I wanted to first start with 100 samples and slowly increase to 1000 samples in a Design of Experiment space.

Comment: If I can obtain an overview of the range of input parameters, then I can smartly scale up the generation of samples for my final model.

I hope it is a bit clearer now.

Comment: so you want to know which parameters have an effect on the probability of failure and how much and so that you can predict the failure without the need of running simulations?

Comment: Yes. And also it can help in further sample generation. If I know that some Parameter A has more importance and that if I know the range, then I can populate my sample in this input parameter range.